# How to verify that all the pins on a NIC card are indeed working?

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I have a laptop here that had some bent pins on its NIC, my boss straightened them out, but there's still one pin that when I look at it, appears a little flat, like it won't touch the end of the cable when plugged in.

So I was wondering, is there a software way to test that all the pins are connected on the NIC?

Comment: Unlikely.  Does the device work?

Comment: It appears to work, but does it connect at the top speed?

Comment: This isn't a stupid question.

Comment: You tell what the top speed is and if your reaching it

Comment: @Ramhound Okay so like a speed test then...you want to answer that so I can give you credit?

Comment: @leeand00 - Sure; Do you transfer at or near  maximum speeds of the card?

Comment: 100 MB per/sec, and I'm guessing 1 GiB per/sec is where this would be noticeable? (mean if it needed to go that fast)

Answer (score 1):

Good software to test it would the OS's Ethernet stack. Plug a wire in - does it connect to the network, at the speeds and duplex expected? Yes? Then the pin is fine the way it is. :)

Comment: Eh, not quite correct. If its a Gigabit NIC and it connects to a Gigabit switch at Gigabit speed: It's OK. If the NIC is 100 Mb/s and the switch too and the connection is 100 Mb/s, you also fine as far as working is concerned, but some don't-care pins might be faulty. In any other combination you can't say for 100% sure what is going on even if the connection appears to be working.

Comment: @Tonny Thank you, this is what I was getting at.

Comment: If they are don't-care pins then they won't effect the speed

Comment: @Ramhound True, if you're just using 100 Mb/s. They are NOT don't care for Gigabit.

Comment: I was about to suggest suggest disassembling the system, plugging in a cable and checking it with a multimeter. This sounds simpler. If it *isn't* even running at fast ethernet speeds its probably worth looking up the 'minimal' pinout fast ethernet uses, and comparing it to the pinout on the connector. I do suspect since the connectors are pairs, the 'loss' of one pin might introduce noise but things should work otherwise.